# Presiono boton submit y me cambia de tab

Tags: php, html

Hola tengo 2 tabs en una pagina con formularios y botones de consulta  en cada una ..al presionar el boton del tab2 realiza la consulta pero se coloca en el tab 1 y tengo que hacer click en el tab 2 para ver el resultado...como puedo resolver esto
agrego codigo

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Anual x Area</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Tipo de Combustible</a></li>

</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">

<section class="content">
  <div class="container-fluid">        
    <div class="row clearfix">
       <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="header">
           <h2>Estadística de área por año</h2> <h4>Combustibles DIESEL Y NAFTA</h4>

          </div>
        <div class="body">

        <form  method="POST" action="chartarea.php" name="frm">
          <div class="row clearfix">
             <div class="col-md-6">
                   <div class="form-group-horizontal">
                          <label class="control-label">Seleccione Area</label>
                          <select class="form-control" name="area" id="area" autofocus>
                             <option></option>
                             <option>SERVICIOS PUBLICOS</option>
                             <option>ESPACIOS VERDES</option>
                             <option>OBRAS MUNICIPALES</option>
                             <option>OBRAS PRIVADAS</option>
                             <option>PARQUE AUTOMOTOR</option>
                             <option>SEGURIDAD</option>
                          </select><br>
                        </div>
                      </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group-horizontal">
                        <label class="control-label">Seleccione año</label>
                        <select class="form-control"  name="año" id="año" value="<?php if (isset($año)) echo $año ?>">
                           <option></option>
                           <option>2016</option>
                           <option>2017</option>
                           <option>2018</option>

                        </select><br>
                      </div>
                   </div>


               <div class="card-footer">


                  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-6">
                    <button name="btConsulta" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Consulta</button>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-default icon-btn" href="#" class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-times-circle" type="submit">Nuevo</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary icon-btn" type="button"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-check-circle" href="hola.php"></i>Salir </button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                 </div>
               </div>
            </div>


          </form>

      </div>
      <h2></h2>


        <div class="row clearfix" >
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card" >
              <h3 class="card-title">Comparativo Anual</h3>
              <div id="barChart">

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>



        </div>
        <button id="btnp" class="btn btn-success">Imprimir</button>
    </section> 
  </div>




<div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">

<section class="content">
  <div class="container-fluid">        
    <div class="row clearfix">
       <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="header">
           <h2>Estadística comparativa x área</h2> <h4>Combustibles DIESEL O NAFTA</h4>

          </div>
        <div class="body">

        <form  method="POST" action="chartarea.php" name="frm">
          <div class="row clearfix">
             <div class="col-md-6">
                   <div class="form-group-horizontal">
                          <label class="control-label">Seleccione Area</label>
                          <select class="form-control" name="area2" id="area2" autofocus>
                             <option></option>
                             <option>SERVICIOS PUBLICOS</option>
                             <option>ESPACIOS VERDES</option>
                             <option>OBRAS MUNICIPALES</option>
                             <option>OBRAS PRIVADAS</option>
                             <option>PARQUE AUTOMOTOR</option>
                             <option>SEGURIDAD</option>
                          </select><br>
                        </div>
                      </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group-horizontal">
                        <label class="control-label">Seleccione Combustible</label>
                        <select class="form-control"  name="combus" id="combus" value="<?php if (isset($año)) echo $año ?>">
                           <option></option>
                           <option>TODO DIESEL</option>
                           <option>TODO NAFTA</option>


                        </select><br>
                        <?php echo 'Iniciando ejecuci&oacute;n<br />';
                        include './prueba.php';
                        ?>
                      </div>
                   </div>


               <div class="card-footer">


                  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-6">
                    <button name="btConsulta" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Consulta</button>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-default icon-btn" href="#" class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-times-circle" type="submit">Nuevo</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary icon-btn" type="button"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-check-circle" href="hola.php"></i>Salir </button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                 </div>
               </div>
            </div>


          </form>

      </div>
      <h2></h2>


        <div class="row clearfix" >
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card" >
              <h3 class="card-title">Comparativo Anual</h3>
              <div id="barChart">

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>



        </div>
        <button id="btnp" class="btn btn-success">Imprimir</button>
    </section> 

  </div>
```

los tabs se llaman home y menu1 y cuando presiono el boton btConsulta me devuelve al tab home y deberia quedarse en el tab menu1...Desde ya gracias

Answer (score 1):

El problema es la clase `active`.  Cada vez que haces un `POST` debes de chequear de donde viene ese `POST` y agregar la clase `active` respectivamente asi:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="<?php if (!isset($_POST['combus'])) echo 'active' ?>"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Anual x Area</a></li>
  <li class="<?php if (isset($_POST['combus'])) echo 'active' ?>"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Tipo de Combustible</a></li>

</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">

<section class="content">
  <div class="container-fluid">        
    <div class="row clearfix">
       <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="header">
           <h2>Estadística de área por año</h2> <h4>Combustibles DIESEL Y NAFTA</h4>

          </div>
        <div class="body">

        <form  method="POST" action="chartarea.php" name="frm">
          <div class="row clearfix">
             <div class="col-md-6">
                   <div class="form-group-horizontal">
                          <label class="control-label">Seleccione Area</label>
                          <select class="form-control" name="area" id="area" autofocus>
                             <option></option>
                             <option>SERVICIOS PUBLICOS</option>
                             <option>ESPACIOS VERDES</option>
                             <option>OBRAS MUNICIPALES</option>
                             <option>OBRAS PRIVADAS</option>
                             <option>PARQUE AUTOMOTOR</option>
                             <option>SEGURIDAD</option>
                          </select><br>
                        </div>
                      </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group-horizontal">
                        <label class="control-label">Seleccione año</label>
                        <select class="form-control"  name="año" id="año" value="<?php if (isset($año)) echo $año ?>">
                           <option></option>
                           <option>2016</option>
                           <option>2017</option>
                           <option>2018</option>

                        </select><br>
                      </div>
                   </div>


               <div class="card-footer">


                  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-6">
                    <button name="btConsulta" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Consulta</button>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-default icon-btn" href="#" class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-times-circle" type="submit">Nuevo</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary icon-btn" type="button"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-check-circle" href="hola.php"></i>Salir </button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                 </div>
               </div>
            </div>


          </form>

      </div>
      <h2></h2>


        <div class="row clearfix" >
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card" >
              <h3 class="card-title">Comparativo Anual</h3>
              <div id="barChart">

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>



        </div>
        <button id="btnp" class="btn btn-success">Imprimir</button>
    </section> 
  </div>




<div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">

<section class="content">
  <div class="container-fluid">        
    <div class="row clearfix">
       <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="header">
           <h2>Estadística comparativa x área</h2> <h4>Combustibles DIESEL O NAFTA</h4>

          </div>
        <div class="body">

        <form  method="POST" action="chartarea.php" name="frm">
          <div class="row clearfix">
             <div class="col-md-6">
                   <div class="form-group-horizontal">
                          <label class="control-label">Seleccione Area</label>
                          <select class="form-control" name="area2" id="area2" autofocus>
                             <option></option>
                             <option>SERVICIOS PUBLICOS</option>
                             <option>ESPACIOS VERDES</option>
                             <option>OBRAS MUNICIPALES</option>
                             <option>OBRAS PRIVADAS</option>
                             <option>PARQUE AUTOMOTOR</option>
                             <option>SEGURIDAD</option>
                          </select><br>
                        </div>
                      </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group-horizontal">
                        <label class="control-label">Seleccione Combustible</label>
                        <select class="form-control"  name="combus" id="combus" value="<?php if (isset($año)) echo $año ?>">
                           <option></option>
                           <option>TODO DIESEL</option>
                           <option>TODO NAFTA</option>


                        </select><br>
                        <?php echo 'Iniciando ejecuci&oacute;n<br />';
                        include './prueba.php';
                        ?>
                      </div>
                   </div>


               <div class="card-footer">


                  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-6">
                    <button name="btConsulta" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Consulta</button>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-default icon-btn" href="#" class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-times-circle" type="submit">Nuevo</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary icon-btn" type="button"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-check-circle" href="hola.php"></i>Salir </button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                 </div>
               </div>
            </div>


          </form>

      </div>
      <h2></h2>


        <div class="row clearfix" >
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card" >
              <h3 class="card-title">Comparativo Anual</h3>
              <div id="barChart">

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>



        </div>
        <button id="btnp" class="btn btn-success">Imprimir</button>
    </section> 

  </div>
```

Comment: No Funciona ..agrege el codigo

Comment: El <?php if (isset($_POST['combus'])) de la primera linea es <?php if (isset($_POST['año'])) pero  lo corregi y no funciona